# How to add permission to a site collection?

Tags: development, javascript, developer

I have a solution that is built with Visual Studio and I have no permission to delete a list or modify a list. I can not even see the lists that are inside current solution.

[image]

so i cant access to list setting. This list is not appearing outside this solution and i could be accessed only by link!

The solution is built in JavaScript.

How to change this situation?

Comment: Please add more details about the problem you are having, and what you need help with. The question is not clear

Comment: @RobertLindgren Check out the update to the question and see if you could help me!

Comment: A SharePoint hosted add-in (as your solution is) would give you as the end user the same permissions as you have on the web where you add the add-in. So if you do not have permissions to delete lists on the parent web, you will not have it in the app by default.

Comment: @RobertLindgren I am using administrator user with full permission. How can i add permission to this site? thanks!

Comment: Strange question maybe, but why would you want to delete a list that is part of an add-in? That seems to kind of break the whole "app" idea

Comment: @RobertLindgren I want to make some changes. Change to view of app a little bit, and to show the lists on home site. Could permissions be modified in visual studio?

Comment: You can create views from where you are in your screenshots.. You have buttons for that...

Comment: @RobertLindgren yes but how to delete a column that is not necessary?

Comment: That is what you do in your Visual Studio solution where you have developed your add-in?

Comment: i hava not build that solution i got it from microsoft!

Comment: You are really confusing me, you write in your question "I have a solution that is built with Visual Studio"

Comment: can you access the list settings page? was that list created by the Add-In solution?

Comment: @RobertLindgren Microsoft used VisualStuid to built it, so i have the solution and i have it on VS!

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE no i cannot access the list settings it was created by add-in solution